# javascript:Display value in textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I`m trying to display default value in textarea,on click it should clear existing data and onblur it should display default text.Following is my code->

```
<textarea class="TextArea" id="appfield" name="appfield" style="height:44px;" rows="2" onfocus="deletetext(this)" onblur="filltext(this)" value="defaulttext"></textarea>
```

value is not displaying in textarea.what`s wrong???We have similar case in this website in Title textbox.I have to implement the same in my case.
Please suggest an answer.

Comment: Textareas are supposed to hold their values inside/between their tagname.

Comment: Are you missing a quote here? `style="height:44px;" rows="2"` and +1 @elias94xx

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to replicate the functionality of the `placeholder` attribute. Why not just use that? There are numerous [polyfills](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) to make it work in older browsers.

Comment: @JamesAllardice:I`m using IE8,placeholder doesn`t work. I have to implement the same case as the Title box of this site have.onBlur, onfocus have to do.But the prob is vallue='default text' itself not displaying.

Comment: @user1495475 - As I mentioned, you can [use a polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) to make `placeholder` work in older browsers. As has already been stated, you need to put the value *inside* the `<textarea>` tags, and get rid of the `value` attribute.

Comment: @JamesAllardice:I got it.I fixed it.By using default value only.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
 <textarea  id="username"  name="username" 
onfocus="if(this.value=='somevalue') { this.value='';this.style.color='#333333';}" 

onblur="if(this.value=='') {this.value='somevalue'; this.style.color='#B2B2B2';}">
somevalue
</textarea>
```

Comment: :I`m sorry I still have a problem of the value="somevalue",it`s not displaying this value.default value worked for me.

Comment: see the edited answer.I wrote a/c to `input type="text"`.i didn't see the textbox

Comment: what font,family is that this website is using in Title textbox?that textbox you`ll get when you click on "Ask Questions".This should apply only for Default Text.Please suggest me.

Comment: `textarea {
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    font-family: Consolas,Menlo,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New,monospace,serif;}` this is for stackoverflow

Comment: but this is not only for default text.Can`t we separate?

Answer (score 2):

the correct way is

```
<textarea ...>defaulttext</textarea>
```

but you should set up a working fiddle (functions included) to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @fabrizo:I`m sorry,wat`s working fiddle??i`m using IE8.placeholder doesn`t work.

Comment: jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com : you could write and share an example demo including markup, css, javascript reproducing your code in short.

Comment: That is the correct way to set the default value, but it won't imitate the placeholder attribute. And much better to post the code here than on another site.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an option and want to use HTML5 you can do it by using placeholder attribute.

```
<textarea 
    class="TextArea" 
    id="appfield" 
    name="appfield" 
    style="height:44px; 
    rows="2" 
    placeholder="default text"
    value=""></textarea>
```

Other option is

```
<textarea 
    onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';"
    onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"
    class="TextArea"
    id="appfield" 
    name="appfield" 
    style="height:44px; 
    rows="2">default text</textarea>
```

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.It worked.I didnt know that defaultValue will be the text entered between tags.Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using JavaScript you can use placeholder. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fB4ZL/).
but placeholder not supported by older browsers. you can use [jquery libratry](http://www.kamikazemusic.com/quick-tips/jquery-html5-placeholder-fix/).

```
<textarea class="FullTextArea" id="applyfieldscontrol" name="applyfieldscontrol" style="height:44px"  placeholder="defaulttext"></textarea>
```